# Writting SQL query to remove product description from database table

Tags: magento2, php, database, query

I have magento 2.1.3 with following scenario:

NL Main Website | NL Main Website Store | NL Store view

EN Main Website | EN Main Website Store | EN Store view

DE Main Website | DE Main Website Store | DE Store view

FR Main Website | FR Main Website Store | FR Store view

DK Main Website | DK Main Website Store | DK Store view

ES main website | ES Main Website Store | ES Store view

I like to remove short product description and long product description from the tables in the Database with SQL query, could anyone help me with writing such query so that it can be done quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[1] Find `attribute_id` in `eav_attribute` table

```
75 - Description
76 - Short Description
```

[2] Go to `catalog_product_entity_text` Table

`entity_id` = `Product Id`

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text WHERE attribute_id IN (75,76) AND entity_id IN (<Your Product Id's>)
```

Comment: Yes but would this remove short description from all stores?  or is the query only good for one store/website at a time?

Comment: If u see table u can add condition related to `store_id` if u don't specify it will remove from all stores